# GridView setOnItemClickListener does not respond to clicks

Tags: android

I am trying to get the selected item in a GridView, but when I click on item, nothing happens.

I don't get any logs from my log code: `Log.i("postion", arg2+"");`

Here is my code:

calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

```
        calendarView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
        {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("postion", arg2+"");

            Button temp = (Button) calendarView.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);

            temp.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.LightGreen));
        }

        });
```

---

My adapter:

```
   public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
            private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
            private final Context _context;
            private final List<String> list;
            private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
            private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                    "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
            private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
                    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                    "October", "November", "December" };
            private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                    31, 30, 31 };
            private final int month, year;
            private int daysInMonth, prevMonthDays;
            private int currentDayOfMonth;
            private int currentWeekDay;
            private Button gridcell;

            // Days in Current Month
            public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                    int month, int year) {

                super();
                this._context = context;
                this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
                this.month = month;
                this.year = year;

                //Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                    //  + "Year: " + year);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
                setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
                //Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
                //Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
                //Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

                // Print Month
                printMonth(month, year);

            }

            private String getMonthAsString(int i) {

                return months[i];
            }

            private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
                return weekdays[i];
            }

            private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
                return daysOfMonth[i];
            }

            public String getItem(int position) {
                return list.get(position);
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return list.size();
            }

            /**
             * Prints Month
             * 
             * @param mm
             * @param yy
             */
            private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
                //Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
                // The number of days to leave blank at
                // the start of this month.
                int trailingSpaces = 0;
                int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
                int prevMonth = 0;
                int prevYear = 0;
                int nextMonth = 0;
                int nextYear = 0;

                int currentMonth = mm - 1;
                String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
                daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

                //Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                        //+ daysInMonth + " days.");

                // Gregorian Calendar : MINUS 1, set to FIRST OF MONTH
                GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
                //Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

                if (currentMonth == 11) {
                    prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                    daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                    nextMonth = 0;
                    prevYear = yy;
                    nextYear = yy + 1;
                    //Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        //  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        //  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
                } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
                    prevMonth = 11;
                    prevYear = yy - 1;
                    nextYear = yy;
                    daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                    nextMonth = 1;
                    //Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        //  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        //  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
                } else {
                    prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                    nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                    nextYear = yy;
                    prevYear = yy;
                    daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                //  Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                    //      + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                    //      + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
                }

                // Compute how much to leave before before the first day of the
                // month.
                // getDay() returns 0 for Sunday.
                int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
                trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

                //Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                //      + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
                //Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
                //Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

                if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && mm == 2) {
                    ++daysInMonth;
                }

                // Trailing Month days
                for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
                    //Log.d(tag,
                        //  "PREV MONTH:= "
                        //          + prevMonth
                            //      + " => "
                            //      + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                            //      + " "
                            //      + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                            //              - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                            //              + i));
                    list.add(String
                            .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                    + i)
                            + "-GREY"
                            + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                            + "-"
                            + prevYear);
                }

                // Current Month Days
                for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                    //Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                        //  + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
                    if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    } else {
                        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    }
                }

                // Leading Month days
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
                    //Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
                }
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = convertView;
                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell, parent,
                            false);
                }

                Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                        .getDefaultDisplay();

                int height = 0;

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    height = size.y;

                } else
                    height = display.getHeight();

                float scaledDensity = getApplicationContext().getResources()
                        .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;

                height = (height / ((int) scaledDensity));

                if (calendarView.getCount() > 35)
                    height = (height - 300) / 7;
                else
                    height = (height - 300) / 6;

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);

                // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
                gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
                gridcell.setLayoutParams(lp);
                //gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

                // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

                //Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
                String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
                String theday = day_color[0];
                String themonth = day_color[2];
                String theyear = day_color[3];

                // Set the Day GridCell
                gridcell.setText(theday);
                gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);

                if(dateWanted.equals(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear))
                    gridcell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.LightGreen));

                //Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
                //      + theyear);

                if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                }
                if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.static_text_color));
                }

                return row;
            }



            public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
                return currentDayOfMonth;
            }

            private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
                this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
            }

            public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
                this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
            }

            public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
                return currentWeekDay;
            }


        }
```

Comment: where do you have this code inside activity onCreate?

Comment: does it crash coz. atleast you should see the log when you click grid items. comment out the other two lines of code and check if you can see the log message.

Comment: No crash, no logs thats what strange...

Comment: Is the `GridView` enclosed in another layout ?

Comment: Yes, its in another layout.

Comment: Does the other layout have an onClickListener? Or does the other layout respond to touch events?

Comment: The other layout have onClickListener and its respond

Comment: Having an `OnClickListener` on parent layout container won't be an issue. GridView's OnItemClickListener will take precedence. Are you adding `OnClickListeners` to elements within GridView's items? That would explain why GridView isn't getting the click event.

Comment: What about your getItem and getItemId methods in your adapter?

Comment: @Lia Pronina please see my adapter edit.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem. The way I solved it was adding the following lines to the getView() method in my adapter:
btn.setFocusable(false);
btn.setClickable(false);
Where btn is the reference to the button.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your item view contains button or other view that got foucus. Try to set android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to item view like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

   <!-- item -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: interesting I didn't know `descendantFocusability` was a thing, thanks.